# How to convert varying formats of a string into a list of int? (python)

Tags: python, regex

```
m = re.match(r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$', string)
start = m.group(1)
end = m.group(2) or start
return list(range(int(start, 10), int(end, 10) + 1))
```

Right now this is able to handle strings in the following format and convert them into a list...

'0-6' results in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

'7' results in [7]

Is there anyway I can change the notation to be able to handle strings in the following format as well...

'1 2 3 4 5' results in [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: Question could do with a better title. If you start with the definite opinion that it should be done with regular expressions, you often won't get the right answer. Title it with *what* you want to do, not *how* you think you want to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions are not all there is to life. In this case, there's really no reason to use regular expressions. Try this, it's over twice as fast as, for example, Shawn Chin's `to_num_list` on the sample data `'0-6 2 3-6'` (for all data I tried on it it was between about 1.9 and 4.5 times as fast):

```
def included_numbers(s):
    out = []
    for chunk in s.split():
        if '-' in chunk:
            f, t = chunk.split('-')
            out.extend(range(int(f), int(t)+1))
        else:
            out.append(int(chunk))
    return out
```

Comment: +1 I agree that regex is an overkill for this question. To deal with unwanted chars, one can easily wrap the relevant block with a `try: ... except ValueError: ...`.

Comment: You might use a `set()` instead of a `list` so that if the user specifies ranges that overlap, the result doesn't contain duplicates.

Comment: @kindall: that would also have the added benefit of ordering them as `hash(i) is i` for `int`s. I won't change the answer though as the order could be important - but using `set()` is a very good idea if it's suitable.

Comment: Didn't realize that hashing `int`s worked like that, very convenient! Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 3):

I would stick to the same notation, then use `re.findall()` to get all matches. Example

```
import re
def to_num_list(instr): 
   out = []
   for m in re.finditer(r'(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?', instr):
      if m.group(2) == None:
          out.append(int(m.group(1)))
      else:
          start = int(m.group(1))
          end = int(m.group(2)) 
          out.extend(xrange(start, end + 1))
   return out
```

This will give you the ability to handle imputs such as `"1 2 3 10-15"` as well. Example usage:

```
>>> to_num_list("0-6")
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> to_num_list("10")
[10]
>>> to_num_list("1 3 5")
[1, 3, 5]
>>> to_num_list("1 3 5 7-10 12-13")
[1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13]
```

and skips over erroneous inputs (which may not necessarily be what you want):

```
>>> to_num_list("hello world 1 2 3")
[1, 2, 3]
>>> to_num_list("")
[]
>>> to_num_list("1 hello 2 world 3")
[1, 2, 3]
>>> to_num_list("1hello2")
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = re.match(r'(?:(\d+)(?:-(\d+))|(?:(\d+)(?:\s+|$))+)?$', string)
```

Then, look in the captures for group 3.

Comment: Although this increases the complexity significantly, so perhaps you should do this seperately.

Answer (score 0):

The two input formats can be matched by non-greedy regex (designated by the ? quantifier after the *):

```
m = re.match(r'^(\d+)[0-9\-\s]*?(\d+)?$', string)
```

Will always extract the first number and last number into m.group(1) and m.group(2) respectively, or if there is only a single number it will be matched in m.group(1)

See [greedy vs non-greedy](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy) in the python docs.

Comment: What if the input is `"1 3 5 2"`?

Comment: The OP did not ask about that input format. If the intent of the question was to process any list of numbers, then your general solution works here where mine fails. However, if the intent is to express an ascending list of numbers like his two examples, my regex is adequate for all cases, and simpler than your solution. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: Fair point. I'm simply working on the grounds that allowing a list of numbers as input yet expecting only an ascending list isn't exactly great design, especially when `"1-5"` is also supported. Often, it is useful to deduce what the _actual_ requirement is as opposed to what is explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a split you can simplify your regex and let the split handle all the space separated list definitions.

```
import re

def answer(string):
    m = re.match(r'(\d+)-(\d+)$', string)

    if m:
        start = m.group(1)
        end = m.group(2) or start
        return list(range(int(start), int(end) + 1))

    return map(int, string.split(' '))
```